# How to open a man page using PHP?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I am writing a PHP command line utility and I'd like my `help` command to open the man page for itself (the helper).

When someone runs this command

```
$ burrito help
```

The following script is run

```
# help.php

$manpage = DIR_BASE.'/packages/burrito/man/burrito.1';

passthru("man ${manpage}");
```

This outputs the man page *contents* correctly, but it doesn't pipe it to the `less(1)` pager like `man` does.

I want the user to be able to scroll the contents of the man page just as they would if they were to type `man burrito`

Comment: Why do you have a `php` script do this as opposed to a shell script, which could easily pipe through less?

Comment: There's no controlling terminal when you're doing passthrough, so there's no way for less to determine how 'big' your screen is so it can start paging.

Comment: @ExplosionPills, there's a lot more the helper is doing that depends on PHP and other PHP libs.

Comment: @naomik you can have a very simple bash script that just has `result=$(php complicated-library-stuff.php); echo $result | less`

Comment: I'll have to give that a try. I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP 5.4 method looks promising, but you don't have a choice if you don't have/can't use PHP 5.4

If you really need php to do this, you can wrap all of the php functionality:

```
#!/bin/sh
#burrito.sh
php burrito.php | less
```

Except for the 5.4 method (apparently) there is no way to run an external pager on the emission of a php script.